# dispose method not getting called

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, dispose

In my main page, I have two tabs, named tab 1 and tab 2.  When switch to tab 2, it has an icon on upper right corner.When icon is clicked, it will open page C.

I notice when I switch from tab 1 to tab2, it will call `dispose` in tab 1. 
When I switch from tab 2 to tab 1, tab2 `dispose` will be called.

However when I click the icon in tab 2 to navigate to page c, `dispose` in tab 2 is not getting called. 
How can I make `dispose` method called when I click the icon to navigate to page C?

Comment: How are you navigating to page C? What method are you calling?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore  In main page, I use `Navigator.pushNamed` to open pageC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `Navigator.pushNamed` method to push page C on top. This creates a stack of pages, so the tabbed pages are not disposed, they're still there just not visibly. Use `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` instead to replace the current page and take the old one off the stack and `dispose` it.

Comment: I use `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`, and it works. But when I press back button, it quit my app instead of back to previous page.

Comment: @JohnJoe You'll have to change your back button to use `pushReplacement` as well. There are some other questions here on SO that can help with that.